# Stuck with parsing a line to array

Tags: javascript, parsing, google-apps-script

I'm in the process of learning Javascript by doing a Google Apps Script that I've been having in mind for a while. Basically I want to put my credit card expenses, which I receive summarized in a mail every day, in a Spreadsheet.

Briefly, I parse the relevant lines of the mail, cut the fields to an array and write to Spreadsheets. Everything works fine.

This is an exemplum of parsed line:

```
S S P EMIRATES  LLC              ABU DHABI         28/07/13          9.46
```

I discovered that some rows like the ones above have the double space in their name. Since I use the double space ("\s\s") to cut the line into the array fields what I get is:

```
S S P EMIRATES,LLC,ABU DHABI, 28/07/13,9.46
```

Instead of:

```
S S P EMIRATES LLC,ABU DHABI, 28/07/13,9.46
```

I thought about deleting it using the RegEx '\W  \W' but then I would also cut the last and the first letters.

Do you have any idea on how could i overcome this?

Comment: Stupid brain. It works and looks like it doesn't bring any further complication. Thank you so much.

Comment: The tag is not appengine. This I about js

Answer (score 0):

Try this split regex

```
\s{3,}
```

That should split by 3+ spaces, and the values inside the array won't have any leading or trailing spaces.